# sound crackling/popping after wake from suspend

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, suspend

I have a windows 7 PC, with built-in sound card in the motherboard and a USB headphone.

After waking from sleep, the sound very often (though not every time) crackles/pops (say, when playing a flash movie on youtube, or play audio from an audio application). The crackling happens even in the audio test from when you 'test' the sound by right clicking on the 'Sound' icon in the tray, selecting 'playback devices'.

However this only happens when i use the USB headset device, and not a normal speaker i plugin via the audio jack in the motherboard.

Another observation is that if the crackling sound happens, then after some time of audio playback, i get a blue screen of death. If i don't play audio, the BSOD doesn't occur.

If i sleep the machine (start menu->shut-down menu -> sleep), then wake it up again, the crackling disappears, and never occurs again until the next time i sleep the machine (after which it *might* happen - it seems random).

I tried restarting the audio services by doing "net stop audiosrv" then "net start audiosrv" in the command line, but that doesn't seem to fix anything.

Has anyone any clue about what could be the problem?

Comment: It sounds like a driver problem. I would recommend updating your audio drivers and all your motherboard chipset drivers. Let me know if this works so I can upgrade it to a full answer.

Comment: What BSOD code are you seeing?  Have you tried different USB ports to see if it acts any differently? As @Simkill suggests, ensure you have the latest drivers installed for all devices.

Comment: I don't actually know how to obtain the drivers for the built-in sound card. I suppose it's part of the motherboard, and hence, i could try updadating the motherboard drivers (how does one do this?)

Comment: @techie007: i haven't recorded the actual error message. I ll do that next time it happens and post it in the question.

Comment: @Psycogeek: i confirm that this only occurs when i use a USB headphone. If i change my audio device to speakers (which connects via the audio jack at the back of the PC), then all works fine. I have only a keyboard and the headphone attached via USB, and neither of them can be adjusted.